# Height 100% of div stretches to window size

Tags: css, html

**Html :**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div>
<div class="test"> test</div>
<br />
<div class="test"> test</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Style :**

```
 <style>

.test{
height:100%;
background-color:red;
}

</style>
```

I have set up this simple page as above to try to discover why it renders the way it does.

- The only css property is set on the height of the 'test' class.
- It results in the two divs being set to the height of the viewport. If i change the size of the window, the two divs will also resize.
- The strange thing is, when fully maximised on my screen, the height of each of the two divs is 939px, and the height of the body is 1878px.

Even thought the height of the divs are set to be 100% of the containing elements

Can anyone explain the order in which css engines process this information, and result in taking the size of the viewport for each of the divs?

Answer (score 0):

Because you set your height in 100%, and css get your browser window height and apply for each element, if you need to set up that one div is display on half window height, just define `height: 50%;`

Here link must be help for you to understand this http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/height

Answer (score 0):

If your div contains the wrapper to which you have set the height then the inner divs sets upoto that wrapper when applying `100% height` but in your case you don't have set the height so it goes to `window height 100%`. You'll be clear from this two demos [demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Z5/) [demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Z5/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both the `.test` divs are wrapped by a single div.

Besides try having this in your css to ensure body is 100%. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96G46/)

```
html,body{
    min-height:100%; 
    height:100%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96G46/

Answer (score 0):

**why it is failing**

you have set `height` for

```
<div class="test"> test</div>
```

in percentage...this means that it will be `100%` of its containing element, that is, `<div>`...so you have to set 100% height of div too...

Keep in mind that whenever you set dimensions in percentage, it is always considered in relative to the parent element of the div.

so, to set the `.test` to `100%` set parent div and body to `100%` too!!

Chedk these fiddles to understand better :

[**what your layout is now**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq6yX/)
 [**what it is supposed to be like**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq6yX/3/)